# how to view selected data via radio button by clicking of button in other android activity

Tags: android, listview

I have no problem yet. Now I want to know how to pick selected data by radio button and show it on next activity. I have fetched data from database via *ArrayAdapter* interface. Also I have added radio button and *textView* via *CustomAdapter* class as extend *ArrayAdapter* create(getView) method in there and create its object in ListView activity. Please help me out.

[image]

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
RadioGroup radioGroup;
RadioButton radioButton;
LayoutInflater inflater;
TextView text_name;
View customview;
int selectedId;
//Context context;
public CustomAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<String> data) {
    super(context,R.layout.customadapter,data);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    try {
         inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
       customview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customadapter, parent, false);
        //by this above two lines and constructor we can add custom layout to listview

        final String show = getItem(position);
        text_name = (TextView) customview.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        text_name.setText(show);
        //object of radio button
        radioGroup=(RadioGroup)customview.findViewById(R.id.radiogrp);
        selectedId=radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        radioButton=(RadioButton)customview.findViewById(selectedId);

        customview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                switch (selectedId){
                    case R.id.rAbsent:
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"absent",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });


        return customview;
    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"error:"+e,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return convertView;
}
```